# How to enable keyboard in Qt android project without textfield

Tags: android, qt

Is there any way by which i can enable android keyboard in Qml(qt) without the use of textfield.

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger keyboard through the [`QInputMethod`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qinputmethod.html) and the [`show`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qinputmethod.html#show) function which are accessible from QML via the [Qt global object](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#qmlglobalqtobject). Minimal example:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true

    // your stuff

    Component.onCompleted: Qt.inputMethod.show()
}
```

The specular function [`hide`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qinputmethod.html#hide) can be used to dismiss the virtual keyboard.

Comment: how can i handle keyboard events

Comment: actually i am having a rectangle as a button and at onClicekd of that i want to show keyboard and pass the entry of keys as a string to a function

Comment: You can't try to exploit `Keys` element or using some native listener in the platform. What about a quick and dirty hidden textfield to store the wrote text?